# All input unresponsive during/after games on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gaming, input, steam

The vast majority of times which I fire up a game on my PC, after a period of play time [random, 15 minutes up to several hours] my system will become unresponsive to all input.

It isn't a full system lockup, I can see various desktop elements still updating [CPU, IO status graphs moving, htop updating], but the system is completely unresponsive to all keyboard, mouse and keypad input. Every now and then this happens while I am still playing the game.

I am having trouble trying to isolate what the cause is. It clearly has something to do with running 3D programs, which leads me to perhaps a 3D driver issue. But why does it kill the inputs? All of my games run through steam; Is it a steam issue?

Which logs and information would be most useful in diagnosing this problem?

My system configuration is as follows:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 x86_64 - 3.16 kernel

  - Has been occurring on the 3.13 kernel also
- AMD A10-7850K APU with R7 GPU
- 32GB RAM
- fgrlx 14.501.1003 [latest stable Catalyst/Omega drivers]

  - The problem has been occuring on the 14.4xx drivers also